# Fastest Display Function for Android

Tags: android, performance

I am doing Video decoding (mpeg2, frame size 360x240) on Android phone with ARM-Cortex 8, running at 1 GHz. The decoding is done in C language, while the display on the screen is being done by Canvas OnDraw method of Android. 
After profiling I see about 50% time is elapsed in OnDraw(). I am not able to digest why OnDraw() is taking so much time.

Is there any better way to display the frames?

Shall be grateful if someone can point me to the right direction.

Rgrds,

Heshsham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. I used surfaceview, and now the performance is much better